# how can i get the names of outlook calendars from pst file using c# or vb?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, outlook-addin

I want to develop an add in Outlook to save the calendars in .ICS format.

I tried this code but it need a class that I should buy :/ !!

```
' Load the Outlook PST file
Dim pst As PersonalStorage = PersonalStorage.FromFile("d:\Data\Emails\PersonalStorage.pst")
' Get the Calendar folder
Dim folderInfo As FolderInfo = pst.RootFolder.GetSubFolder("Calendar")
' Loop through all the calendar items in this folder
Dim messageInfoCollection As MessageInfoCollection = folderInfo.GetContents()
For Each messageInfo As MessageInfo In messageInfoCollection
    ' Get the calendar information
    Dim calendar As MapiCalendar = CType(pst.ExtractMessage(messageInfo).ToMapiMessageItem(), MapiCalendar)
    ' Display some contents on screen
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " & calendar.Subject)
    ' Save to disk in ICS format
    calendar.Save("Calendar\" & calendar.Subject & ".ics", AppointmentSaveFormat.Ics)
Next messageInfo
```

Comment: What does *"but it need a class that I should buy"* mean?

Comment: I found this code in this link http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/emailnet/Save+Calendar+Items+from+Outlook+PST+to+Disk+in+ICS+for                                                                                               I have to move a little in my project :/

Answer (score 1):

Calendars in Outlook are represented by the folders with Outlook items inside. The Folder class provides the  GetCalendarExporter method which reates a [CalendarSharing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866956(v=office.15).aspx) object for the specified Folder. Be aware, the GetCalendarExporter method can only be used on calendar folders. An error occurs if you use the method on Folderobjects that represent other folder types.

The CalendarSharing class provides the [SaveAsICal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862395.aspx) method which exports calendar information from the parent Folder of the CalendarSharing object as an iCalendar calendar (.ics) file.

The following VBA example creates a CalendarSharing object for the Calendar folder, then exports the contents of the entire folder (including attachments and private items) to an iCalendar calendar (.ics) file.

```
Public Sub ExportEntireCalendar() 
 Dim oNamespace As NameSpace  
 Dim oFolder As Folder  
 Dim oCalendarSharing As CalendarSharing  
 On Error GoTo ErrRoutine 
 ' Get a reference to the Calendar default folder  
 Set oNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set oFolder = oNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar) 
 ' Get a CalendarSharing object for the Calendar default folder. 
 Set oCalendarSharing = oFolder.GetCalendarExporter 
 ' Set the CalendarSharing object to export the contents of 
 ' the entire Calendar folder, including attachments and 
 ' private items, in full detail. 
 With oCalendarSharing 
 .CalendarDetail = olFullDetails 
 .IncludeWholeCalendar = True 
 .IncludeAttachments = True 
 .IncludePrivateDetails = True 
 .RestrictToWorkingHours = False 
 End With 
 ' Export calendar to an iCalendar calendar (.ics) file. 
 oCalendarSharing.SaveAsICal "C:\SampleCalendar.ics"  
 EndRoutine: 
 On Error GoTo 0  
 Set oCalendarSharing = Nothing  
 Set oFolder = Nothing  
 Set oNamespace = Nothing  
Exit Sub 

ErrRoutine:  
 Select Case Err.Number  
 Case 287 ' &H0000011F  
 ' The user denied access to the Address Book.  
 ' This error occurs if the code is run by an  
 ' untrusted application, and the user chose not to  
 ' allow access.  
 MsgBox "Access to Outlook was denied by the user.", _  
 vbOKOnly, _  
 Err.Number & " - " & Err.Source  
 Case -2147467259 ' &H80004005  
 ' Export failed.  
 ' This error typically occurs if the CalendarSharing  
 ' method cannot export the calendar information because  
 ' of conflicting property settings.  
 MsgBox Err.Description, _  
 vbOKOnly, _  
 Err.Number & " - " & Err.Source  
 Case -2147221233 ' &H8004010F  
 ' Operation failed.  
 ' This error typically occurs if the GetCalendarExporter method  
 ' is called on a folder that doesn't contain calendar items.  
 MsgBox Err.Description, _  
 vbOKOnly, _  
 Err.Number & " - " & Err.Source  
 Case Else  
 ' Any other error that may occur.  
 MsgBox Err.Description, _  
 vbOKOnly, _  
 Err.Number & " - " & Err.Source  
 End Select 
 GoTo EndRoutine  
End Sub
```